# Brother scanner not found in xsane,

Tags: ubuntu, sane, brother

I have reinstalled Kubunutu 18.10 the previous week. After the reinstallation I cannot make my scanner work. I have a Brother DCP-9010CN scanner/printer on a network location.

I installed the driver and the printer works out of the box. The scanner has been found by `brscan-skey -l`, the result of this is:

```
DCP-9010CN        : brother3:net1;dev0  : 192.168.0.43         Active
```

`brsaneconfig3 -q` results in

```
Devices on network
  0 DCP-9010CN          "DCP-9010CN"        I:192.168.0.43
```

During the installation the only error it gives is:

```
Packet 'ia32-libs' does not have a candidate for installation
```

Trying to find the scanner from SANE using `scanimage -L` and `sane-find-scanner` does not give any results. When I check on the scanner itself it finds my computer. But when I push from the device to my computer the computer starts the app but does not scan anything.

I cannot find anything wrong in this installation.

The [driver install tool](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=be&lang=nl&prod=dcp9010cn_eu_as&os=128&flang=English) I used came from Brother themselves. The commands that I used for installing the drivers are:

```
sudo su
bash {untarred driver file} DCP-9010CN
```

On all the questions of the installer I answered 'Yes'. For selecting the source of the scanner/printer I selected the IP address and gave the correct IP to it.

The installed packages are:

```
dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                       1.0.2                                       all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                   0.2.4-1                                     amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan3                                       0.2.13-1                                    amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  dcp9010cncupswrapper:i386                     1.1.2-1                                     i386         Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  dcp9010cnlpr:i386                             1.1.2-1                                     i386         Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions

dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

lscpu
Architectuur:              x86_64
CPU-modus(sen):            32-bit, 64-bit
Bytevolgorde:              Little Endian
CPU's:                     4
Online CPU's-lijst:        0-3
Draden per kern:           1
Kernen per voet:           4
CPU-voeten:                1
NUMA-nodes:                1
Producent-ID:              GenuineIntel
CPU-familie:               6
Model:                     60
Modelnaam:                 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:                  3
CPU-frequentie (MHz):      3351.143
max. CPU-frequentie (MHz): 3800,0000
min. CPU-frequentie (MHz): 800,0000
BogoMIPS:                  6799.88
Virtualisatie:             VT-x
L1d-cache:                 32K
L1i-cache:                 32K
L2-cache:                  256K
L3-cache:                  6144K
NUMA-node0 CPU('s):        0-3
Vlaggen:                   fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts flush_l1d
```

Comment: How did you install the driver? And where did you get the driver? ... Brother seems to have a [driver available for download](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp9010cn_eu_as&os=128) in 32 and 64 bit packages.

Comment: I added the install procedure to the question

Comment: It looks like you've installed the wrong package for your architecture...  what is the output of `lscpu` ... and also `dpkg --print-architecture`

Comment: Added output of commands in question.

Comment: The additional information shows that you installed the wrong driver for your kernel architecture... you need to remove the driver you installed and install the `amd64` version on the page I linked to above... it's under the **Scanner Drivers** section and called **Scanner driver 64bit (deb package)**

Comment: When I run dpkg -l it does show that the scanner driver is amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue. Some symbolic links was missing.
Created the links with:

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib64/libbrscandec* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

Fixed the problem

Comment: Yes, thank you, this fixed the problem for me on Ubuntu 21.10. 

Answer (score 5):

I came across this while searching for a solution to the same problem and want to report mine:

brsaneconfig3 will add a line to `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` to load the Brother module. Upgrading the OS may remove that module again, which leads to the same effect. If that happens, the solution is to add the line again:

```
brother3
```

I presume brsaneconfig2 and brsaneconfig4 work similarly, with the numbers 2 or 4 in place of 3.

Comment: Great answer! Minor corrections:
The file is `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`. Also, for brsaneconfig4, add `brother4` in the file instead of `brother3`.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the typo. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I'm on Debian Bullseye and this was the solution. Note that on Debian this is better to create a new file `/etc/sane.d/dll.d/brother.conf` to avoid having your changes overwritten when upgrading `libsane-common`.

Comment: Perfect, this restored things that broke sometime around Debian 11.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the distro, the problem may be missing dependencies.   For opensuse tumbleweed, the package can be installed using `zypper`:

```
sudo zypper in ./brscan3-0.2.13-1.x86_64.rpm
```

However, the installed shared object has a missing dependency:

```
> ldd /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6ad70000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f391c8a4000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f391c888000)
libusb-0.1.so.4 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f391c742000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f391c73c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f391c571000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f391ca02000)
```

Installing `libusb` through the package manager solved the issue.

Comment: Perfect! This holds true for e.g. opensuse Leap 15.2. Thanks for figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a Brother MFC-L8690CDW

The Brother supplied tool lists the following devices on my network

```
$ brsaneconfig4 -q
* MFC-L8690CDW [    192.168.45.2]  MFC-L8690CDW
  MFC-L8690CDW [  192.168.45.101]  Brother_MFC-L8690CDW_series
```

It seems the IP address mapping from my router changed inbetween initial setup and now. There is only one device online.

My solution was as follows:

- assign the printer/scanner a fixed IP in my local router
- edit the following configuration file /opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg to use the correct IP

xsane could then detect my scanner again, using Xubuntu 18.04 and the Brother supplied .deb driver packages.